# Cycles - Normal maps seam when baking HighPoly->LowPoly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normal-map

Yes, there are already plenty of similar questions here, none has an answer. The normals are inverted on my baked low-poly mesh :

[image]

I have this high poly mesh :

[image: HP]

and this low poly mesh (the borders don't match exactly because this is a simplified scene, I deleted a lot of stuff) :

[image]

The low-poly UVs are decent (again, partial mesh only; seam selected) :

[image]

I baked the normals using Cycles, CPU only, both 8bit and floating-point textures. When connecting the normal map to the diffuse color, it gives this :

[image]

Ok, why not, that's how tangent space works.

However, when connecting to the diffuse's normal slot, it gives the image above. This one is NOT ok.

[image]

It seems that Cycles' baking tool does not use the same tangent basis than the renderer... Does anyone know a fix ?

.blend : http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43471

Comment: Please make sure the title of your question is specific to your problem and not just the general subject.

Comment: @RayMairlot Better this way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last image there is the problem - you are connecting normal map texture directly into the vector slot.

Please connect it through the *Normal Map node* (Shift+A > Vector > Normal Map):

[image]

Comment: I googled lots of stuff, but I never thought it would be this part... Feeling stupid. Thanks !